# VMWare Fusion reach localhost high port from guest

Tags: vmware, vmware-fusion

I've searched docs for this but having no luck... Running VMware 8.5.7 for Mac, from the Windows **guest** I need to reach a port like 8888 that is available to my host (but actually running in VirtualBox on the host -- not sure if that matters but could be important to know.)

Any suggestions?  There seem to be very few configuration options for VMware ports, or maybe I'm just looking in the wrong place.)

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the suggestions here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235011/vmware-fusion-connecting-to-hosts-web-server-from-guest