# Send command to MacBook Terminal from Pycharm installed on virtual Windows

Tags: python, macos, terminal, vmware-fusion

**Background:**
Through VMWare Fusion installed on my MacBook, I have Windows installed virtually in the VMWare Fusion environment. On the Windows, I have Pycharm IDE through which I run automated python program to control bench instruments from Keysight and Techroniks. No issues.

PS- The instrument drivers are available only for Windows, thats the reason I am using Windows virtually on MacBook

**Question:**
From Pycharm (installed on virtual Windows), I would like to send any command (say, print Hello World) to the Terminal of the MacBook.
How to do this and what would be the command syntax (or package needed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single package to do this.

At a minimum, your Mac host would need to run a server process. Then the VM would need to be on a host network bridge such that it is remotely addressable. Then, you can write a client that sends RPC requests to the host's server process.

At a low-level, you can use [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) library, but you may want something higher level like `httpserver`.

Related - [VMWare fusion: connecting to host's web server from guest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235011/vmware-fusion-connecting-to-hosts-web-server-from-guest)

The other option without external dependencies would be to communicate over a file-system share.

If you want to install external software, then you can introduce a remote message queue or database.